# Retrieve the Deleted / Edited tweets list using twitter REST API

Tags: twitter, twitter-rest-api

Can anyone please share me the idea to retrieve the deleted and Edited tweet list(user timeline) after the given time? using twitter rest API.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this isn't part of the REST API, I think you have 3 choices here.

1. Avoid permanently caching things like timelines and tweets, and refetch timelines which will be updated after deletes.
2. Periodically refetch timelines and process the deltas for overlapping time ranges.
3. use the streaming API, which unfortunately would introduce a huge amount of complexity https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/messages-types#status_deletion_notices_delete